# How to solve this differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

I have problem with solving this differential equation:

```
y''[t]+y'[t]+n y[t] = 1
```

where `n = 1,2,3,4`

Comment: `Equal` is written as `==` because `=` means `Set`. So you can write `Table[DSolve[y''[t] + y'[t] + n y[t] == 1, y[t], t], {n, 4}]`

Comment: Such differential equations can be solved directly. First solve the homogenous equation with the Ansatz-function ' y[t]:=Exp[r*t]', then solve the characteristic polynominal and finally do a variation of constants. Mathematica can help in all of this steps :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
eqn = y''[t] + y'[t] + n y[t] == 1;

sol = DSolve[eqn, y, t][[1]]

(* {y -> Function[{t}, 
   1/n + E^(1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 n]) t) C[1] + 
    E^(1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 n]) t) C[2]]} *)
```

where `C[1]` and `C[2]` are arbitrary constants.

Verifying that the solution satisfies the equation,

```
eqn /. sol // Simplify

(* True *)

Table[{n, y[t] /. sol}, {n, 4}] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

For `C[2] == C[1]`

```
Table[{n, y[t] /. sol /. C[2] -> C[1] // FullSimplify}, {n, 4}] // 
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To `Plot`, both arbitrary constants must be given values. For simplicity, let `C[1] = C[2] = 1`

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[
    Tooltip[
     y[t] /. sol /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 1}, n],
    {n, 4}] // FullSimplify],
 {t, 0, 2 Pi},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 14] & /@ {"t", "y[t]"}),
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. :) is there a simple way to draw the four solutions on one phase graph?